# Add text after a Grand Total moving row in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to add a cell with a value under a **Grand Total** row of Pivot Table in Excel? As the Grand Total is a moving row, how to add a text under that cell?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know there is no simple way to do this.  My recommendation would be placing your pivot table into a seperate sheet, running a macro to refresh your pivot, copying it to a new sheet and after pasting table putting your text under it via this macro.

Comment: Another solution would be moving your data to MS Access.  You can create and save queries.  Then create a report and put your sample footer in report's footer section.

Comment: I agree with @Ozgun Senyuva, that the solution is in using vba. However, you don't need to move the pivot table to another sheet. Some clues: 1) the vba to look into is the Worksheet_Change event and 2) implement the footer as a shape (textbox) that you move when the pivot table resizes.

Comment: Try using footers via page layout on the sheet - that might fit your needs